# Start EXEs from bat file

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch-file

In the command line I can easily write `start my.exe` however when I do that in a bat file and execute it I get a cmd window called my.exe.

How do I start exe's and shortcuts from a bat file? The bat file must be nonblocking. I want to launch 4+ apps at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the help text with `start /?`, you will see that the first parameter is for the window title.  You can use `/b` to not start a new window.

Therefore, what you want is...

```
start "" /b my.exe
```

Comment: *> the first parameter is for the window title*   …but it only applies if the parameter is in quotes (e.g., `start "cool app.exe"` won’t work); otherwise you can use just `start calc.exe`

Comment: `start "" "my.exe"` seems to work as i want